# Trying to parameratize a sql line and can't seem to balance the quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to take the line below and make the date and time stamp a parameter that is passed in, but I can't seem to get around the unbalanced apostrophes.

So this:

```
@tsmobject = N'Server\Instance\BackupName_2013-02-01_22.35.bak',
```

should end up looking something like this?

```
@tsmobject = 'N'Server\Instance\backupName_' + @time + '.bak'',
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL Server, could you please clarify which RDBMS in the tags?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@tsmobject = N'Server\Instance\backupName_' + @time + '.bak'
```

But it depends on the datatype and format of `@time` - make sure this is in the correct format to match your backups.

Comment: If @time is smalldatetime, for example, you might need to to a conversion.   ex: convert(nvarchar(20),@time,120)